# Is is possible to run UI-based applescript without logged in user session?

Tags: macos, github-actions, applescript, ios-simulator

I am working on end-to-end test automation that runs with GitHub actions and uses custom MacOS runner images that we have full control of.

The problem I need to solve is to shake an iOS simulator somehow when UI tests are running on the CI runner.

The only solution I found so far is to use AppleScript like this or similar:

```
    tell application "Simulator" to activate
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Simulator"
            set frontmost to true
            keystroke "z" using {command down, control down}
            keystroke "z" using {command down, control down}
        end tell
    end tell
```

This script is executed from the Python framework that runs test automation, which is executed from the GitHub Actions workflow.

This works perfectly locally, and it works on CI if I log in to the runner via screen sharing, but as soon as I turn off screen sharing, this stops working - no errors from the script, but the action is not executed as expected therefore leading to the failure of the test.

The question is:
Is it possible to run UI-based automation with AppleScript without being logged in physically to the Mac? What could be an issue with my approach if it is?

I have a hard time finding any information on the issue and would appreciate any help on that topic.